# Are there any 3rd party UI libraries for Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, view, components

I've seen specialized Android UI libraries like for charting, but none for alternate implementations of controls and containers.  Are there any?

Comment: There was a [very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555536/android-ui-external-libraries) asked recently (with answers).

Comment: Thanks.  The question is similar, but there is only one answer and it is unsatisfactory because it offers resources on how to extend Android components, NOT on Android UI libraries.

Comment: This is a good compilation of libs including UI related stuff: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078479/what-android-3rd-party-libraries-are-there?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 2):

I saw http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/ mentioned recently on another SO question. I haven't looked at it or used it myself, but it appears to be the kind of thing you're looking for.

Comment: this link doesn't work for me , Its 2 years for your answer do you have a new suggestion.

Comment: Works for me. Click 'Source' to see the source code, and instructions for downloading it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is.  [DroidUX](http://www.droidux.com) is a professional UI/UX component library for the Android platform. It contains reusable widgets that are fast and easy to use in your project, such as ActionBars, Dashboard, QuickActions, GalleryFlow, Editors, Wheel widgets, and other type of widgets.

Using the DroidUX widgets in your project is no different than the stock widgets. You can even use some of the DroidUX widgets as drop-in replacement for the stock widgets.

Check it out here: http://www.droidux.com